# Can properties from Mixin become a nested object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a python client to interact with a REST API.  The API uses JSON, and some of the objects I need to create are nested and have a lot of optional parameters.  I'm trying to represent the nested JSON with classes for the base objects, and Mixins for all the optional nested properties.  I'm pretty new to python, so any suggestions on a good way to manage nested JSON without repeating a bunch of code would help too.

Here's an example:

```
class paramMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, prop1, prop2, **kwargs):
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


class baseObject(paramMixin):
    def __init__(self, name, prop1, prop2, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    super().__init__(prop1, prop2)
```

Doing that produces an object like this:

```
>>> myObj = baseObj('myName', 'myProp1', 'myProp2')
>>> myObj.prop1
'myProp1'
```

What I'd like to happen is this:

```
>>> myObj = baseObj('myNmae', 'myProp1', 'myProp2')
>>> myObj.paramMixin.prop1
'myProp1'
```

I know I could obviously have all the properties that need to be nested as dictionaries, but I'm trying to abstract that away if I can.

I know this could work:

```
class baseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name, prop1, prop2)
        self.name = name
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
```

Then define it like this:

```
>>> myObj = baseObject('myName', {'paramMixin': 'myProp1'}, {'paramMixin': 'myProp2'})
>>> myObj.paramMixin.prop1
'myProp1'
```

A lot of the Mixin objects I'm trying to define can be reused in more than one type of object.  That's why I'm trying to find a way to define it once and only build it in if I need it.

Comment: just create an paramMixin instance inside `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `paraMixin` obj inside baseObject's `__init__` method.

```
class paramMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, prop1, prop2, **kwargs):
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


class baseObject:
    def __init__(self, name, prop1, prop2, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.paramixin = paramMixin(prop1, prop2, **kwargs)

myObj = baseObject('myNmae', 'myProp1', 'myProp2')
myObj.paramixin.prop1 
# myProp1
```

Comment: Well that's simpler than what I was trying to do ;).  This will work.  Thank you very much.